# ServiceStack how to send a custom response after a logout?

Tags: c#, servicestack

To logout I use the logout service i.e. /auth/logout.

But I'm always receiving an HTTP 200 response.

I'm wondering if there is a way to send custom messages, e.g. LogoutFailed or LogoutSucceeded as a string?

I'm using ServiceStack 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logout request always succeeds, if there was an error it would return a HTTP Error Response. So you can just assume the logout was successful, or redirect them to your preferred page using the `continue` queryString, e.g `/auth/logout?continue=/custom-page`